# Combining specific sql query results into one string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query;

```
SELECT custom.name, instance_id 
FROM table1 tb 
WHERE tb.instance_id = 1111 OR tb.instance_id = 2222
```

This returns the following results;

```
test, 1111
test1, 1111
test3, 1111
tabletest, 2222
tabletest1, 2222
tabletest2, 2222
```

I would like the ability to match the instances_id, and combine the matching rows into a single string.

i.e.

```
test;test1;test3
tabletest;tabletest1;tabletest2
```

I can get a single string but at the moment this grabs all the results and puts it into a single string.

```
STUFF((
SELECT custom.name + ';'
FROM table1 tb 
WHERE tb.instance_id = 1111 OR tb.instance_id = 222
FOR XML PATH(' '), TYPE.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 0, ' ')
```

this results in

```
test;test1;test3;tabletest;tabletest1;tabletest2
```

Unfortunately I cannot upgrade past sql server version 15 which perhaps limits me.

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server version 15" ? If you're talking about the program version - then "v15" is SQL Server **2019** which is the absolutely newest version available on the market - of course you cannot upgrade past this version - there is no newer version at all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlation clause in the subquery.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT v.instance_id,
       STUFF((SELECT ';' + tb.name 
              FROM table1 tb 
              WHERE tb.instance_id = v.instance_id
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
             ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
                    ), 1, 1, ' '
            )
FROM (VALUES (1111), (2222)) v(instance_id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19a39115807e48b2a127856d298d3b5d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
drop table if exists dbo.tTable;
go
create table dbo.tTable(
  [name]                varchar(100) not null,
  instance_id           int not null);

insert dbo.tTable values
('test',1111),
('test1',1111),
('test3',1111),
('test',2222),
('test1',2222),
('test2',2222);
```

Query

```
select instance_id, 
      stuff((select ';' + cast([name] as varchar(100))
             from tTable c2
             where t.instance_id = c2.instance_id
             order by [name] FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [value1]
from tTable t
group by instance_id;
```

Output

```
instance_id value1
1111        test;test1;test3
2222        test;test1;test2
```